# Monitoring System for the cloud?

Tags: monitoring, cloud-computing, munin, ganglia

I need a monitoring system, much like ganglia / nagios that is build for the cloud.

I need it to support :

- Adding / removing nodes dynamically. (Node shuts down, dose not imply node failure...)
- Dynamic node based categorization, meaning node can identify them self as being part of group X (ganglia gets this almost right, but lacks the dynamic part...)
- Does not require multicast support (generally not allowed in cloud based setups)
- Plugins for recent cool stuff such as Hadoop, Cassandra, Mongo would be cool.

More features include: External API, web interface and co.

I've looked at Ganglia, munin and they both seem be almost there (but not exactly). I would also go for reasonably priced Software as Service solution.

I'm currently doing research, so Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Maxim

Answer (score 2):

I was going to suggest ganglia but I see you already considered it. There's also [Icinga](http://www.icinga.org/) and [Reconnoiter](https://labs.omniti.com/labs/reconnoiter), that one being a very new addition. Reconnoiter has a hosted version with an amazing interface, called [Circonus](http://circonus.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Really what you are talking about is some sort of config mgmt system to manage your monitoring. In essence you need monitoring to be provisioned when you provision a new host and deprovisioned when you shutdown a host. In house we are using puppet to provision our hosts into nagios and then manually removing as that is not a common task. As time goes by the deprovision process will be automated as well.

I would look at chef and puppet as the top contenders in this space.